# Publishing on Google Play to a limited number of users

Tags: android, google-play

I want to publish my app to a limited set of users (Not country and carrier specific). I searched on the internet and found [this](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2494992?hl=en). However this has lead to confusion, at the start the document says that we can create a private channel to distribute apps throughout an organization.

> A Google Apps for Business, Education, or Government domain can have a Private Channel on the Google Play Store. The Google Apps domain administrators can allow domain users to register with the Android Developer Console to publish Android applications to the Private Channel. The publisher account owner who registered with the Android Developer Console must be a Google Apps user in the same domain, such as internal IT staff, and not external developers.

But at the end the document says:

> **Can I publish an app to a specific group of users?**
>
> No. But you can publish an app targeting a specific country or specific device models.

If anyone has a better insight on this, please enlighten me. I want to publish an app internal to my organization what are the possible ways?

Comment: Do you use Google Apps in your organization? That is a requirement for that specific private channel publishing.

Comment: No we do not, however if need be we can! Is this service paid? On top of Dev Console fee?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think its better to do like following:-

**Alpha- and beta-testing**

If you are planning to go alpha- and beta-testing route, it’s best to start with a small group of alpha testers (perhaps employees of your company, or a few fellow developers) and then move on to a larger group of beta testers.

Follow this link:-
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en

Its just simple you have to create an **community** of the employees with their **google** **account**.and simple add this community as a **beta tester**.so everyone get the mail regarding the link to download an app and acceptance of permissionbecome an tester.

Comment: This is an option and I had come up with this initially, but if Google has provided an option to publish to a limited number of users I think it would be technically correct to use that feature.

Comment: Yes you are right.But I don't think the google had come with these features.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding of the document you quote is that the app developer must be inside the domain serviced by the Private Channel. An external developer (one who is outside the domain) cannot publish to that specific domain.

Thinking it through, we have to ask "how could Google control publishing to a specific domain?" As soon as we ask that we can see all sorts of security and control issues. We could imagine a malicious developer publishing a trojan app that is targeted at a particular business they wanted to damage.

So there are the two paths: a private Channel publishing to a given domain, and the Alpha / Beta path [recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24177028/1715960) by Born To Win.